# One Proposal, Two Submissions (NSF GRFP and NDSEG)

Tags: graduate-school, funding, research-proposal, nsf

I'll be applying this coming fall to start a master's program in fall 2024 and plan on applying for both the GRFP and NDSEG for potential funding. I was wondering if there are any guidelines about submitting the same proposal to both. I know both have different requirements but my plan is to just write one and change it to fit the requirements of the other. I'm just not sure if that is allowed and am worried that if I do do that, it could make my application un-reviewable.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what everyone does. More generally, the NSF does not require, expect, or even encourage people to follow the plan in the proposal. They understand that things change as people move from college to a PhD. The point of the proposal is just to show that you understand the context and purpose of your undergraduate work.